# Нужно при нажатии на текст в таблице чтоб появлялось модальное окно с возможностью редактировать, javascript

Tags: javascript

Прошу помочь. Нужно сделать так чтоб при нажатии на комментарий, появлялось модальное окно с этим комментарием и с возможностью редактировать(сохранять изменение не нужно)

```js
console.log(data);

function callback(a) {
  const tr = `
    <tr>
    <td> ${a.postId} </td>
    <td> ${a.id} </td>
    <td> ${a.name} </td>
    <td> ${a.email} </td>
    <td> ${a.body} </td>
    </tr>
    `
  document.getElementById("root").innerHTML += tr;

}

data.forEach(callback);

function click() {
  console.log(this)
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100 % ;
  border - collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: solid 1 px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>JS-HW-5-6</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Сторінка коментарів</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>postId</th>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>body</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="root">

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="./data.js"></script>
  <script src="./script3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Сохранить не получится, нужен ЯП который имеет право записывать в файл, javascript это не умеет

Comment: Что не получается у вас?

Comment: Не могу понять как функцию клик подключить и как правильно её написать, чтоб при нажатии на текст всплывало окно с возможностью редактировать

Answer (score 0):

решение

```
var bubu = document.getElementsByClassName('bubu');
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
for(let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
modal.innerText = bubu[i].innerText;
modal.style.display = 'block';
});`}
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите